# JavaScript filesize calculation

Tags: javascript

I want to calculate the file size of the file selected by user  from file browser window. How can I achieve it without using activexobject in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use id for input and get size when onChange:

```
<input type=file id=fileSelector>

fileSelector.onchange = () => {
    alert(fileSelector.files[0].size);
}
```

Another way, use can use API to get file size, like:

```
fileSelector.onchange = () => {
  let fileBlob;
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', fileSelector.files[0]); 
  fetch(formData).then((res) => {
    fileBlob = res.blob();
    return fileBlob;
  }).then((fileBlob)=>{
    // file size: fileBlob.size
    console.log([fileBlob.size, fileBlob.type]);
  });
}
```

Hope that it helps